# Is there a way to dynamically update a window name in Gnu Screen?

Tags: gnu-screen

I want to Gnu Screen to dynamically rename the current Screen window after the current directory. Is there any way to get Screen to do this? If it requires patching the source, I'd like to know that's the only option.

Comment: See http://superuser.com/questions/244299, though it's a quite old question ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is indeed seems to be possible, check out [Automagic screen window titles](http://retout.co.uk/blog/2007/08/23/automagic_screen_window_titles) and [Dynamic Titles](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/html_node/Dynamic-Titles.html) section from the screen manual.

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068806/gnu-screen-can-you-automatically-name-a-window-after-the-last-invoked-program to rename a window after the last executed command.

Comment: your link to the "Dynamic Titles" page is dead :(

Answer (score 0):

This function will give you a command call `title` which you can then use to change the screen window title.

```
title() { printf $'\ek%s\e\\' "$1"; }
```

If you're using a decent shell (like `zsh`) you have `precmd` and `prexec` hooks from which you can run any command before and after a prompt. I suggest you use these to update the window title.

Patched the above together from info found on: [GNU Screen: Title Examples](http://aperiodic.net/screen/title_examples)

(Sorry, brief answer, I'm in a bit of a hurry and might expand this later.)